# Saving AnyObject to NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shopify

I'm currently working on a Swift application that interacts with the Shopify API through their [Mobile Buy SDK](https://docs.shopify.com/mobile-buy-sdk/ios). I'm having issues saving the cart to the device. Everything else works fine, but when I use the following code to save the cart to the device:

```
  func saveCart() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cart, forKey: "cart")
    println("cart saved")
  }
```

I receive the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object <BUYCart: 0x7fb5e30512f0> for key cart'
```

Comment: NSCoding is not sufficient; NSUserDefaults only accepts plist types.

Answer (score 0):

From the `NSUserDefaults` class reference:

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of `NSData`. For more details, see *[Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How should I go about saving this object then?

Comment: Same Question. Have you got the answer. Stuck with it from two days

Comment: hello I have same problem ? do you have any solution?